# MRO with multiple inheritance in python with calls to super() __init__

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

Bear with me as I am getting started with Python.
Say I have a multiple inheritance scenario:

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self, Animal):
    print(Animal, 'is an animal.');

class Mammal(Animal):
  def __init__(self, mammalName):
    print(mammalName, 'is a warm-blooded animal.')
    super().__init__(mammalName)
    
class NonWingedMammal(Mammal):
  def __init__(self, NonWingedMammal):
    print(NonWingedMammal, "can't fly.")
    super().__init__(NonWingedMammal)

class NonMarineMammal(Mammal):
  def __init__(self, NonMarineMammal):
    print(NonMarineMammal, "can't swim.")
    super().__init__(NonMarineMammal)

class Dog(NonMarineMammal, NonWingedMammal):
  def __init__(self):
    print('Dog has 4 legs.');
    super().__init__('Dog')
    
d = Dog()
```

Upon printing, I get this:

```
Dog has 4 legs.
Dog can't swim.
Dog can't fly.
Dog is a warm-blooded animal.
Dog is an animal.
```

When **init**() is getting called from Dog class, the **init**() of *NonMarineMammal* is called which makes sense since MRO starts with left-most base class for a child class in case of multiple inheritance.
Again, the **init**() of *NonMarineMammal* calls its super()'s **init**() which is *Mammal*.
So my confusion is why I got

```
Dog can't fly.
```

instead of

```
Dog is a warm-blooded animal.
```

Why the above order isn't followed? Is it something to do with **init**() function or the same behaviour stands for other methods as well?

Comment: You sometimes have the class name in your init method instead of "animalname" or something. I don't know if that's a problem, but it is confusing to read at least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)